# What are the addressing modes of these avr commands?

Tags: avr, register, addressing

What are the addressing modes of ldi, ld, and st. I think ldi is register direct, ld is register indirect, and st is also register indirect. Are those the right addressing modes?

Answer (score 1):

LDI is immediate since the value is specified in the opcode itself. LD and ST are indirect since they use an index register.